# Encode URL with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode

I am using an API that doesn't accept JSON in the requests' bodies. It uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Thus, if I have to send this `dict`:

```
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': {
        'k': 3,
        'v': 4,
        'l': {
            'p': 5,
            'q': 6,
        },
    },
}
```

It have to be encoded like this:

```
a=1
b=2
c[k]=3
c[v]=4
c[l][p]=5
c[l][q]=6
```

However, `urllib.parse.urlencode` won't parse the `dict` this way. Instead it's going to encode `c` content literally and put within it (`c={encodeddict}`).

I tried to implement some encoder like this by myself, but I couldn't get to deal with multiple nested `dicts`. I only managed to encode 1-level `dicts` (like `c[k]=3`), but not recursively to the last level (`c[l][p]=5`, for example).

What is the best way to achieve this kind of encoding in Python 3?

Comment: Well as far as I know the `[` and `]` are not allowed, so it will result in something like `'c%5Bk%5D=4'`.

Comment: Allowed or not, this is the way the API receives. Anyway, even encoding `[` and `]`, urlencode doesn't deal with nested dicts. For instance, the `dict` of the question become `a=1&b=2&c=%7B%27k%27%3A+3%2C+%27v%27%3A+4%2C+%27l%27%3A+%7B%27p%27%3A+5%2C+%27q%27%3A+6%7D%7D`, which decoded is something like `a=1&b=2&c={'k':+3,+'v':+4,+'l':+{'p':+5,+'q':+6}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion:

pass your dict to dict_to_urlencoded(), and it'll return encoded format string based on your description. (unsorted)

```
def dict_to_urlencoded(d):
    return kv_translation(d, "", "")


def kv_translation(d, line, final_str):
    for key in d:
        key_str = key if not line else "[{}]".format(key)
        if type(d[key]) is not dict:
            final_str = "{}{}{}={}\n".format(final_str, line, key_str, d[key])
        else:
            final_str = kv_translation(d[key], line + key_str, final_str)
    return final_str
```