# Parsing dicts in querystrings in Python?

Tags: python, query-string

It's fairly standard to encode querystrings like this:

```
urlencode({
  'a': {
    'b': 1
  },
})
# a[b]=1
```

However:

```
parse_qs('a[b]=1')
# {'a[b]': 1}
```

Does Python have a built-in function to parse querystrings containing dicts? If not, what's a clean way to do so?

Comment: Isn't that just JSON? - I'm not aware of any other standard for representing list/map structures.  I'm a back-end guy.  I haven't seen any other standard from the server's perspective...not that that means a whole lot.  I'm curious to learn if there is a more standard answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535876/encode-url-with-nested-dictionaries
But after Googling around, I suppose there is no "standard" for URL-decoding nested structure. In my company, we end up passing around JSON strings inside the URL, although it quickly runs into the limitation of the length of query string in HTTP GET.

Comment: @AdityaSantoso that's how Node, Ruby, and PHP encode querystrings. Python's the only different one